# load actionscript 3 made swf in actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to ask a question.
If i make a swf with actionscript 3 and load it as movie in actionscript 2 will it loose the interactivity?
I want to use the slider component and other things.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load AS3 swf files into an AS2 swf unfortunately (the other way around is possible with some limitations).

> SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 cannot load SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0. This means that SWF files authored in Flash 8 or Flex Builder 1.5 or earlier versions cannot load ActionScript 3.0 SWF files.

Source: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000011.html

Comment: Yes, i just test it and nothing happened... pitty... do you know if there is a way to add event listener in actionscript 2 to a slider? i made to sliders with a draggable controlball. i want to interract with each other and when i move the first the other one move the opposit direction.

Comment: Yes, you can add a mouse down event and then start listening to mouse move (and on mouse up you stop listening to mouse move), or you can use startDrag().

Comment: i have the code var startval=225/2;
var maxval=bar_heat._y + 225;
control_heat.onPress = function(){
 this.startDrag(true, bar_heat._x - 2.5, bar_heat._y, bar_heat._x - 2.5 , bar_heat._y + 225);
}
control_heat.onRelease = control_heat.onReleaseOutside = function(){
 this.stopDrag();
}
control_heat.onMouseMove = function(){
 newpoint = new Object();
 newpoint.x = this._x;
 newpoint.y = this._y
 _root.bar_heat.globalToLocal(newpoint);
 num = newpoint.y;
 heattxt.text = Math.round(num);
 _root.slider_humi.control_humi._y=this._y; 
}  The other slider is like this. I test it but it works only on 1